# Why is my Sniper Elite V2 Auto-minimizing after "Alt-Tab"?

Tags: sniper-elite-v2

I recently bought [Sniper Elite V2](http://store.steampowered.com/app/63380/?snr=1_7_suggest__13) on Steam, which is by the way, a incredible game.

Last week it started to behave weirdly.

Once i first open the game, everything is fine,  but after the first "alt-tab", once i bring the game to foreground again, i can see my "windows mouse" on the game screen, and even tho i can use the keyboard in the game without any problems, as soon as i "click" on the screen ( to shoot, for example ) the game window minimizes. I can bring it again to foreground but the same problem keeps hapening over and over until i reopen the game completely.

Any idea of what might be happening here ?

Thanks in advance and sorry about the bad english

Comment: This sounds like something is causing Windows to think the game is losing focus.  From what I've experienced, this tends to happen on games you play at fullscreen.  Have you tried changing it to play in a window?

Comment: Yes this is what it looks like. No, i haven't tried windowed mode yet. Fullscreen makes the game alot better to play =/

Comment: If V2 has the option, try using 'Fullscreen (windowed)' ( or equivalent ) mode. It will keep the game windowed, but with certain properties of fullscreen ( I have started to play all of my games with this setting. Useful 2+ monitors. )

Comment: Just checked, it does not have the option to play in any other mode than fullscreen. I can only play with the resolution and details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

> I know it's quite late but I was browsing for solutions to this
>   problem, after receiving the game this week and coming across the same
>   issue.
>
> Seeing this question has no accepted answer and is quite high ranked
>   on google search results I thought I add my 2 cents for what worked for
>   me and maybe it can come in handy for future users as well.

---

I had the same issue on Windows 7. Every time I tried using my mouse and clicked it minimized the game again. I have 2 monitors so I don't know if that has anything to do with it or not.

After browsing for about 30 minutes and reading up on several possible solution the one that worked for me was to [**disable desktop composition**](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/22803-desktop-composition-disable-program.html) on the `SniperEliteV2.exe`

> Before anyone asks, I have no idea why this worked or how the windows
>   Aero feature can force a game to minimize that way.

This is how you apply it:

- Go to the `bin` folder in the location your game is installed i.e: `..\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Sniper Elite V2\bin`
- right-click the `SniperEliteV2.exe`
- Select the `Compatibility` tab
- Enable `disable desktop composition`
- click `apply`

See screenshot for reference below.
(I even applied this change to my executable while the game was running and it worked)

Hope this works for anyone else with the same issue.

[image]

Comment: Late it or not, you got the answer tick :D I simple game up resolving this problem. Perfect timing :D

Answer (score 2):

Taken from here:  http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Sniper_Elite_V2#Window_Focus_Issues

Use "Windows XP (SP3)" compatibility mode.

Confirmed working for me using Windows 8 x64 (which has no "disable desktop composition" option, because no Aero).

Answer (score -1):

If anyone has this problem, that's because the game loses focus. Windows thinks the game as background program and overrides it's focus function. Hit ctrl+enter to switch to window mode and hit ctrl+enter again to switch back to fullscreen mode to refresh functions. It will solve the problem, too.

Answer (score -4):

Ctrl+Enter twice will solve it

Comment: Why will this solve it?  Try to give a bit more information, please.